# Profile based on UserId - Measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

How to view information on view based on User Id ( used in measurement protocol ) .  I am sending the following request but it does not seem to get registered in google analytics for user id based view.

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?&ul=en-US&v=1&tid=UA-xxxxxx-2&cid={9ddbf6d0-1909-4ea8-afd0-bcbfbbfd1c3e}&t=pageview&dt=Share%20tab&dp=Share%20tab&uid=hsjfy4782jduyth6k4

I notice that it still comes under the All Website data ( default view )

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Audience Analysis" section to understand your audience characteristics, including reporting/grouping based on the User ID.

As far as I understand, it is not possible to search or query based on the CID parameter directly as it is considered internal data for Google to use grouping multiple events under one user, and to track returning users across days or weeks.